# BUG on my code & improve function - split by query

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have this example dataframe

```
nucleotide  start  end    strand  block_id  query  pid       
AE002161.1  5537   6724   1       1         0      AAF73616.1
AE002161.1  6714   7727   1       1         0      AAF37902.1
AE002161.1  7687   10839  -1      1         1      AAF37903.1
AE002161.1  10826  13900  -1      1         0      AAF37904.1
AE002161.1  13887  15596  1       1         0      AAF37905.1
AE002161.1  18606  19487  -1      2         0      AAF37910.1
AE002161.1  19822  19998  -1      2         0      AAF37911.1
AE002161.1  19982  21625  1       2         1      AAF37912.1
AE002161.1  21728  22996  1       2         0      AAF37913.1
AE002161.1  23108  25063  1       2         0      AAF37914.1
AE002161.1  36276  36575  -1      3         0      AAF37924.1
AE002161.1  36680  38116  -1      3         0      AAF37925.1
AE002161.1  38120  39928  -1      3         1      AAF37926.1
AE002161.1  40478  41497  1       3         0      AAF37927.1
AE002161.1  41864  42256  1       3         0      AAF37928.1
AE002161.1  45880  46554  1       4         0      AAF37933.1
AE002161.1  46556  47884  1       4         0      AAF37934.1
AE002161.1  47902  48408  1       4         1      AAF37935.1
AE002161.1  48412  49254  1       4         1      AAF37936.1
AE002161.1  49264  50379  1       4         0      AAF73618.1
AE002161.1  50395  51903  1       4         0      AAF73619.1
```

and this function

```
library(tidyverse)

splitq <- function(data){
  a <- data %>%
    mutate(., block_id = group_indices(., nucleotide, block_id) ) %>%
    group_by(nucleotide, block_id) %>%
    mutate(old=cumsum(query)) %>%
    mutate( query = ifelse( old > 1 , 0,  query ) ) %>%
    ungroup()

  a_max <- max(a$block_id)

  b <- data %>%
    arrange( desc(row_number() ) ) %>%
    mutate(., block_id = group_indices(., nucleotide, block_id) + a_max ) %>%
    group_by(nucleotide, block_id) %>%
    mutate(old=cumsum(query)) %>%
    mutate( query = ifelse( old > 1 , 0,  query ) ) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    bind_rows(a) %>%
    select(-old)
}
```

when I run this function I get this result

```
nucleotide  start  end    strand  block_id  query  pid         type 
AE002161.1  50395  51903  1       8         0      AAF73619.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  49264  50379  1       8         0      AAF73618.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  48412  49254  1       8         1      AAF37936.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  47902  48408  1       8         0      AAF37935.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  46556  47884  1       8         0      AAF37934.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  45880  46554  1       8         0      AAF37933.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  41864  42256  1       7         0      AAF37928.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  40478  41497  1       7         0      AAF37927.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  38120  39928  -1      7         1      AAF37926.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  36680  38116  -1      7         0      AAF37925.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  36276  36575  -1      7         0      AAF37924.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  23108  25063  1       6         0      AAF37914.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  21728  22996  1       6         0      AAF37913.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  19982  21625  1       6         1      AAF37912.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  19822  19998  -1      6         0      AAF37911.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  18606  19487  -1      6         0      AAF37910.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  13887  15596  1       5         0      AAF37905.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  10826  13900  -1      5         0      AAF37904.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  7687   10839  -1      5         1      AAF37903.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  6714   7727   1       5         0      AAF37902.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  5537   6724   1       5         0      AAF73616.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  5537   6724   1       1         0      AAF73616.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  6714   7727   1       1         0      AAF37902.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  7687   10839  -1      1         1      AAF37903.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  10826  13900  -1      1         0      AAF37904.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  13887  15596  1       1         0      AAF37905.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  18606  19487  -1      2         0      AAF37910.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  19822  19998  -1      2         0      AAF37911.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  19982  21625  1       2         1      AAF37912.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  21728  22996  1       2         0      AAF37913.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  23108  25063  1       2         0      AAF37914.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  36276  36575  -1      3         0      AAF37924.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  36680  38116  -1      3         0      AAF37925.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  38120  39928  -1      3         1      AAF37926.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  40478  41497  1       3         0      AAF37927.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  41864  42256  1       3         0      AAF37928.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  45880  46554  1       4         0      AAF37933.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  46556  47884  1       4         0      AAF37934.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  47902  48408  1       4         1      AAF37935.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  48412  49254  1       4         0      AAF37936.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  49264  50379  1       4         0      AAF73618.1  CDS  
AE002161.1  50395  51903  1       4         0      AAF73619.1  CDS
```

EDIT: Which seems **not** nice, since its generate some redundancy, it should create 5 blocks not 8.

I just want to split by `query == 1`. So, for each query I should have n lines above and n below (the same rows in same order). This operation should perform by block_id.

When two neighbor `query == 1` be side by side like

```
AE002161.1  45880  46554  1       4         0      AAF37933.1
AE002161.1  46556  47884  1       4         0      AAF37934.1
AE002161.1  47902  48408  1       4         1      AAF37935.1
AE002161.1  48412  49254  1       4         1      AAF37936.1
AE002161.1  49264  50379  1       4         0      AAF73618.1
AE002161.1  50395  51903  1       4         0      AAF73619.1
```

It should return

```
AE002161.1  45880  46554  1       4         0      AAF37933.1
AE002161.1  46556  47884  1       4         0      AAF37934.1
AE002161.1  47902  48408  1       4         1      AAF37935.1
AE002161.1  48412  49254  1       4         0      AAF37936.1
AE002161.1  49264  50379  1       4         0      AAF73618.1
AE002161.1  50395  51903  1       4         0      AAF73619.1
AE002161.1  45880  46554  1       5         0      AAF37933.1
AE002161.1  46556  47884  1       5         0      AAF37934.1
AE002161.1  47902  48408  1       5         0      AAF37935.1
AE002161.1  48412  49254  1       5         1      AAF37936.1
AE002161.1  49264  50379  1       5         0      AAF73618.1
AE002161.1  50395  51903  1       5         0      AAF73619.1
```

It means, I don't care if all block_id changes since it is unique per block (don't repeat anywhere in the output).

Also, in this example I have only the same nucleotide, but it may have different nucleotide.

But when I run this against 591MB file with 2070926 lines where 332236 are `query == 1` where 330409 of them are distinct I got some errors.

No error message are generated, but I miss some queries.

Do someone have any idea what is going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed function

```
splitq <- function(data){
  a <- data %>% filter(query == 1) %>% mutate( old = block_id, new = row_number()) %>% select(pid, new, old)
  b <- data %>% 
    left_join(a, by = c("block_id" = "old")) %>%
    group_by(new) %>%
    mutate( query = ifelse( pid.x == pid.y, 1, 0), block_id = new ) %>%
    arrange(nucleotide, block_id, start, end) %>%
    select(-pid.y, -new) %>%
    rename(pid=pid.x) %>%
    ungroup()
}
```